# How to change the <img> attr SRC with jQuery on wordpress, since it have <?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ) ?>

Tags: jquery, wordpress, image, src

I want to change image attr src on wordpress with click. It works perfectly offline, however, not on wordpress.

the buttons to click

```
<ul>
<li class="bt-color">
<img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ) ?>/img/blue.png" alt="blue">
</li>
<li class="bt-color">
<img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ) ?>/img/purple.png" alt="purple">
</li>
<li class="bt-color">
<img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ) ?>/img/pink.png" alt="pink">
</li>
</ul>
```

the image to change is

```
//offline
<label for="id1">
<img src="img/main-image.png" />
</label>

//online with wordpress
<label for="id1">
<img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ) ?>/img/main-image.png" />
</label>
```

The code to change

```
/* offline code */   
$('.bt-color').click(function() {
    var alt = ($(this).children().attr('alt'));
    if ( alt === 'blue' ){
        $("label[for='id1']").children().attr('src', 'img/main-image-blue.png' );
    } else if ( alt === 'purple' ){
        $("label[for='id1']").children().attr('src', 'img/main-image-purple.png' );
    }
});

/* online with wordpress, my failed trial */   
jQuery('.bt-color').click(function() {
    var alt = (jQuery(this).children().attr('alt'));
    if ( alt === 'blue' ){
        jQuery("label[for='id1']").children().attr('src', '<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ) ?>/img/main-image-blue.png' );
    } else if ( alt === 'purple' ){
        jQuery("label[for='id1']").children().attr('src', '<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ) ?>/img/main-image-purple.png' );
    }
});
```

Doing offline it works, however, online on server, it doesn't replace the image...

how can I fix that? I thank everyone for reading and try to help.

Comment: Where are you putting the jQuery code?

Comment: I am putting on the <head> with  wp_enqueue_scripts

Comment: Please show the complete function to add the script.

Comment: all right friend, I will do it on another answer

Comment: add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'apiki_scripts' );
function apiki_scripts()
{
wp_enqueue_script( 'apiki-slide', 
 get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/js/livesey.js',
 array( 'jquery' ), 
 filemtime( TEMPLATEPATH . '/js/livesey.js' ), 
 false 
);
}

Comment: You can edit your question.  But if your jquery is livesey.js file, then you can't intermix PHP in that.

Comment: really? So I must find another way